# Why am I getting NaN when all variables & inputs are numbers?

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

I know I haven't set up validation yet, but I can't figure out why I'm getting NaN in 2/5 results fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The fields that are producing NaN are interestPay and gainLoss. I know that gainLoss is related to interestPay, so if I can fix that one, it will probably fix both.

I've tried using parseFloat and parseInt on monthlyBalance after it's calculation, but that doesn't work.

Any advice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Bankrate Payment Calculator Test | Todd Adel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculateThis(form) {
    //Get a reference to the form id="calculator"
    var theForm = document.forms["calculator"];

    var balance = parseFloat(document.getElementById('balance').value);
    var charge  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('charge').value);
    var spending1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('spending1').value);
    var spending2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('spending2').value);
    var spending3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('spending3').value);
    var cashBack1 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('cashBack1').value)) / 100;
    var cashBack2 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('cashBack2').value)) / 100;
    var cashBack3 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('cashBack3').value)) / 100;
    var everythingElse = parseFloat(document.getElementById('everythingElse').value);
    var cashBackEE = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('cashBackEE').value)) / 100;
    var payOff = parseFloat(document.getElementById('payOff').value);
    var interestRate = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('interestRate').value)) / 100;

    // Calculate monthlyBalance
    var monthlyBalance = document.getElementById('monthlyBalance');
    monthlyBalance.innerHTML  = "$" + (balance + charge - payOff);

    // Calculate interestPay
    var interestPay = document.getElementById('interestPay');
    interestPay.innerHTML = "$" + monthlyBalance * interestRate / 12;

    // Calculate cashBackEarned
    var cashBackEarned = document.getElementById('cashBackEarned');
    cashBackEarned.innerHTML = "$" + ((spending1 * cashBack1) + (spending2 * cashBack2) + (spending3 * cashBack3) + (everythingElse * cashBackEE));

    // Calculate gainLoss
    var gainLoss = document.getElementById('gainLoss');
    gainLoss.innerHTML = "$" + (cashBackEarned - interestPay);

    // Calculate earnedRewards
    var divobj = document.getElementById('earnedRewards');
    if (cashBackEarned >= 0) {
        var earnedRewards = true;
        divobj.innerHTML = "Yes";
    } else {
        earnedRewards = false;
        divobj.innerHTML = "No";
    }

}    


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="calculator" class="form-inline">
<div id="container">

   <div id="inner" class="row">   

    <div class="row header"><h1>Are you paying for cash-back rewards?</h1></div>
    <div class="row subhead"><h2>Fill out the form below to find out now</h2></div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What was your balance left over from last month?:</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="balance" id="balance" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">How much did you charge this month?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="charge" id="charge" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">Choose a spending category
          <select name="spending_category" size="1" class="input-med">
            <option value="1">Spending Category 1</option>
            <option value="2">Spending Category 2</option>
            <option value="3">Spending Category 3</option>

          </select>
      </div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="spending1" id="spending1" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What was your % Cash Back?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>%</span><input class="input-mini" name="cashBack1" id="cashBack1" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">Choose a spending category
          <select name="spending_category" size="1" class="input-med">
            <option value="1">Spending Category 1</option>
            <option value="2">Spending Category 2</option>
            <option value="3">Spending Category 3</option>

          </select>
      </div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="spending2" id="spending2" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What was your % Cash Back?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>%</span><input class="input-mini" name="cashBack2" id="cashBack2" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">Choose a spending category
          <select name="spending_category" size="1" class="input-med">
            <option value="1">Spending Category 1</option>
            <option value="2">Spending Category 2</option>
            <option value="3">Spending Category 3</option>

          </select>
      </div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="spending3" id="spending3" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What was your % Cash Back?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>%</span><input class="input-mini" name="cashBack3" id="cashBack3" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data span12"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">Add Category</a></div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What did you spend on everything else?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="everythingElse" id="everythingElse" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">What was your % Cash Back?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>%</span><input class="input-mini" name="cashBackEE" id="cashBackEE" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">How much did you pay off?</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="payOff" id="payOff" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data">
        <div class="span10 question">Interest rate on credit card</div>
        <div class="span2 input"><span>%</span><input class="input-mini" name="interestRate" id="interestRate" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row data span12"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" onclick="calculateThis()">Calculate</a></div>

    <div class="row span12"><h2>Results</h2></div>
    <div id="results">
      <div class="row data blue">
          <div class="span10 question">Monthly Balance</div>
        <div id="monthlyBalance" class="span2 input"><span>$</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row data white">
          <div class="span10 question">How much will you pay in interest?</div>
          <div id="interestPay"  class="span2 input"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row data blue">
         <div class="span10 question">Cash back earned this month</div>
          <div id="cashBackEarned"  class="span2 input"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row data white">
          <div class="span10 question">How much $ did you gain / lose?</div>
          <div id="gainLoss"  class="span2 input"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row data blue">
          <div class="span10 question">Did you pay for your rewards?</div>
          <div id="earnedRewards"  class="span2 input"></div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- End #results -->

  </div> <!-- End #inner -->

</div> <!-- End #container -->
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to paste only relevant part instead of full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
var monthlyBalance = document.getElementById('monthlyBalance');
```

This retrieves the DOM element with ID 'monthlyBalance'.

Later on you have:

```
interestPay.innerHTML = "$" + monthlyBalance * interestRate / 12;
```

This means that you are trying to multiply a DOM element (which is not a number) with interestRate / 12.

Try changing your code to the below:

```
// Calculate monthlyBalance
var monthlyBalance = balance + charge - payOff;
var monthlyBalanceDomObject = document.getElementById('monthlyBalance');
monthlyBalanceDomObject.innerHTML  = "$" + monthlyBalance;
```

Comment: Interestingly it fixed the calculation for gainLoss, but not for interestPay. I tried using the same method for interestPay. Now, the NaN error is gone, but it yields a blank result in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Loos like you've missed off `.value` from the function

```
document.getElementById('monthlyBalance')
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById('monthlyBalance').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you get a DOM element: `var monthlyBalance = document.getElementById(..);`, then later you try to use that element within a calculation: `interestPay.innerHTML = "$" + monthlyBalance * interestRate / 12;`.

You need to create separate variables for the `#monthlyBalance` element and its calculated value.

And the same stands for `cashBackEarned` and `interestPay` when you're calculating value for `#gainLoss`.

Comment: After creating the new variable for the HTML element, can I continue to use the monthlyBalance variable in other calculations?

Comment: Yes, if you have separated the variables, like `monthlyBalanceElement = document.getElementById('monthlyBalance'); monthlyBalance = balance + charge - payOff;`. And don't forget to separate `cashBackEarned` element and `interestPay` element and corresponding values too.

Answer (score 0):

```
interestPay.innerHTML = "$" + monthlyBalance * interestRate / 12;
```

At this point monthlyBalace is a html element maybe try this:

```
interestPay.innerHTML = "$" + (balance + charge - payOff) * interestRate / 12;
```

Then you're making the same mistake with cashBackEarned and interestPay. You expect them to be numbers but they are html elemnts.